# SMTP with one mail

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp

I used SMTP with my spring boot application, the SMTP server is working when I use in host smtp.gmail.com.
but i want to use one.mail.
when i run the application it shows me a problem !
How to fix this problem and thank's

> ERROR 10864 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
> failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException:
> Couldn't connect to host, port: mailout.one.com, 587; timeout -1;
> nested exception is:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:
> connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException:
> Couldn't connect to host, port: mailout.one.com, 587; timeout -1;

application.properties:

```
spring.mail.host = mailout.one.com
spring.mail.username = abc@artec.com
spring.mail.password = ****
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
```

MailSender.java:

```
import ...
@Component
public class SmtpMailSender {
    
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;  
    
    public void send(String to, String subject, String body) throws MessagingException {
        
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper;
        
        helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, false); // true indicates
                                                       // multipart message
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setTo(to);
        helper.setText(body); // true indicates html
        // continue using helper object for more functionalities like adding attachments, etc.  
        
        javaMailSender.send(message);
            
    }
}
```

Controller.java :

```
...
smtpMailSender.send("abc@artec.com", "app","test"); 
...
```

Comment: Try using telnet to connect to that port and host and see if it works. You can also try a java socket connection. Just to make sure that the port is open and there no firewall preventing the connection.

Comment: @j.i.t.h.e.s.h, for the firewall, there is no problem and also the port works when I linked SMTP with gmail, but I do not know why does not work with onemail !!

Comment: Gmail uses a different server and port so if it works for that doesn't means it will work for onemail. The error message is very clear that it is unable to connect to that onemail host on that specified port so it looks more like network connectivity issue instead of SMTP/Java that is why I asked to check on network layer.